# Get Bash script to check directory for files and perform action based on each file

Tags: bash

it's my first time posting, I have used code examples from here in the past, and appreciate the help.

I currently have a large Bash script with dozens of functions, and it's growing, and becoming harder to manage. Each function really is a totally seperate module, and for ease of development, and the ability to easily allow community contributed modules without me needing to integrate each one, I would like to add functionality to have separate module files, that the main script would automatically see, and add in.

Currently I have: (super simplified)

script.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

function one {
 stuff
}

function two {
 different stuff
}

one
two
exit
```

But would prefer to have a script that automatically checks a directory (say, "modules/"), and any file with the suffix .module (e.g. lights.module) would be loaded into a menu (I have a good functional whiptail menu system already).

I have tried a load of stuff, from Google, and from stackoverflow, but I seem to have hit a wall.

I can create a file with the list of module names - so a module can be dropped in at will, and it appears in the list:

```
for entry in /home/tony/scripts/test/modules/*
do
 echo "$entry" >> modules.list # Append the name of present modules to the list of modules
done
```

But how do I let my script know these module names, and do something with them (i.e. bung them into a whiptail menu, and call them if selected).

Comment: This question reminds me a lot of the [module](http://linux.die.net/man/1/module) utility. If you're trying to do this with bash script, I'd recommend using an array to load any modules you'd like and pop off any you don't want. I may be able to add an example later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered having a folder, and then running:

```
for module in somefolder/*.module; do
    source $module
done
```

If need be, you can alphabetically sort your modules in the desired execution order

Comment: If modules are sourced, it could be a requirement that each module contain a line outside any function such as: `modulelist+=('modulename')` where modulelist is an array. If there are several functions in a module file, each can be added to the list. (`modulelist=(${modulelist[@]} 'modulename')` if the += operator causes problems in a particular version of bash.)

Comment: Out of dozens of modules, a user may only want to run one or two. I think I really need to get the list of module names, with each name being assigned a unique variable. Perhaps an array is where I should be looking? (New to arrays).

Comment: @tonyhughes so, sure, you could create an array where the key is the module name and the value is the path to the module, let your user's choose, and then source (or run) only the one you want. Not sure we are answering your question... just in case, though, here's a [tutorial on bash arrays](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks. Bash arrays are clearly what I need. I now have an array being automatically populated with the names of whatever *.module files exist. But how can I assign each element in the array to a unique variable? E.g. code to check the array, and if there are three elements, assign the content of first one to $VARIABLE1, then second to $VARIABLE2 etc.

Comment: Reading further, are the elements already accessible as variables?

Comment: Cracked it, thanks to pointers here, with: for i in "${modulelist[@]}"; do

Comment: But still dont know how to increment variable names automatically. e.g. array element 1 = VARIABLE1 so I have a predictable stream of variables to incorporate elsewhere

Comment: @tonyhughes here, use this: `i=$((i+1)`

Answer (score 0):

KSH has autoload for that sort of thing - [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x6632.html) seems to imply a port is available for Bash.